# Filtering Table by values(new to HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filtering

Can anyone tell me how to filter a table using javascript triggered by button press that can check to columns Mapping error/Squad Error for values bigger than 0 and return only those rows through filtering?

```
    <table class="FILTER">
  <thead><tr class="firstrow"><th>league</th><th>Home</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Away</th><th>Mapping Error</th><th>Squad Error</th></tr></thead><tbody>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>AFC Rushden & Diamonds</td><td>-</td><td>Barwell</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Alvechurch</td><td>-</td><td>Royston Town</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Banbury Utd</td><td>-</td><td>Redditch Utd</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Biggleswade Town</td><td>-</td><td>Bromsgrove Sporting</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Coalville Town</td><td>-</td><td>Leiston</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Kings Langley</td><td>-</td><td>Nuneaton Borough</td><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Lowestoft Town</td><td>-</td><td>Hednesford Town</td><td>6</td><td>6</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Needham Market</td><td>-</td><td>Stratford Town</td><td>0</td><td>6</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Rushall Olympic</td><td>-</td><td>Peterborough Sports</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Stourbridge</td><td>-</td><td>Hitchin Town</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
   <tr><td>The BetVictor League Southern Premier Central Division</td><td>Tamworth</td><td>-</td><td>St Ives Town</td><td>0</td><td>4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>league</td><td>Home</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Away</td><td>Mapping Error</td><td>Squad Error</td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Please try to find a solution yourself first and post some of your JavaScript code here if you need help. The community will not write code solutions for you without own effort. A good starting point for you is get used to the DOM and check basic JavaScript references on Mozilla MDN.

Comment: Thank you I will check the sources you have provided I have tried the various methods I have seen online but have yet to finds a solution.

Comment: it will be better if you can use datatable

Answer (score 0):

Using the `filter` function from JQuery, you can specify what rows you want to select. You can check the documentation for this function [here](https://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.filter() to filter from your data.

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter